# ArcGIS Identity Tool Output Fields

Tags: arcobjects, c#, identity

I am using the `Identity` tool which takes 3 parameters: `in_features`, `identity_features`, and `out_features`. Does the output `FeatureClass` need to have fields that are a combination of the fields in `in_features` and `identity_features`?

I keep getting an error when I the `out_features` only contains the fields in `in_features` and not both `in_features` and `identity_features`.

```
public static void PerformIdentityOverlay(string workSpace, string inputFeatureClassName, string identityFeatureClassName, string outputFeatureClassName)
{
     IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory")) as IWorkspaceFactory;
     IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(workSpace, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;
     IFeatureWorkspaceManage featureWorkspaceManage = featureWorkspace as IFeatureWorkspaceManage;

     IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(workSpace, 0);

     IFeatureClass identityFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(identityFeatureClassName);

     IFeatureClass inputFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(inputFeatureClassName);
     IFields inputFieldsFromFeatureClass = inputFeatureClass.Fields;
     String shapeFieldName = inputFeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;



     IFeatureClassDescription fcDesc = new FeatureClassDescriptionClass();
     IObjectClassDescription ocDesc = (IObjectClassDescription)fcDesc;

     // Use IFieldChecker to create a validated fields collection.
     IFieldChecker fieldChecker = new FieldCheckerClass();
     IEnumFieldError enumFieldError = null;
     IFields validatedFields = null;
     fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = workspace;
     fieldChecker.Validate(inputFieldsFromFeatureClass, out enumFieldError, out
                                    validatedFields);

     IFeatureClass outputFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(outputFeatureClassName, inputFieldsFromFeatureClass, ocDesc.InstanceCLSID,
                                                ocDesc.ClassExtensionCLSID, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, shapeFieldName, "");

     Geoprocessor gProc = new Geoprocessor();
     Identity ident = new Identity(inputFeatureClass, identityFeatureClass, outputFeatureClass);
     IGeoProcessorResult result = gProc.Execute(ident, null) as
                IGeoProcessorResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that to use an Identity Tool you need to pass it the `string` of the location for the `FeatureClass`. This was somewhat confusing as the parameters state that it must be an `Object`.

```
Identity ident = new Identity();
        ident.in_features = inputFeatureClassLocation;//String
        ident.identity_features = identityFeatureClassLocation;//String
        ident.out_feature_class = outputFeatureClassLocation;//String
```

Comment: Right, the tool is going to create the output object for you. The docs are like that sometimes, they say object when they really should say the name of a new object.